# How do I save the variable name in awk sums?

Tags: awk

I need to write a script which calculates the five biggest influencing factors in a table.

I have a table with 32 columns. I need to calculate the sum of column 32 for every unique item for every column, then get the five biggest ones.

I have a code like:

```
awk -f’;’ '{for(i=1;i<=29;i++)sums[$i]+=$32} END{for (i in sums) print sums[i], ":", i}' as.csv | sort -rn
```

This works perfectly (sums column #32 for every unique item), but I cant determine, which sum is from which column.

Sample columns:

```
Aircraft: Type;Altitude bin;Aircraft: Make/Model;Pilot notified;Damage type
```

Sample output:

```
4766 TRUE
4608 A-230
4560 Airplane
4556 Caused damage
3932 FALSE
3773 2
```

I would like to know which value comes from which column like:

```
4766 TRUE - Pilot notified
4608 A-230 - Aircraft: Make/Model
4560 Airplane - Aircraft: Type
4556 Caused damage - Damage type
3932 FALSE - Pilot notified
3773 2 - Altitude bin
```

Comment: I don't understand your question: isn't the column of each sum the key in `sums`? Please show a real input file, the current output for that file, and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post the input file, I made up this based on the example. If the summand is the last column the code will work as is, otherwise change it to the right index.

sample data (first row has the column names)

```
Aircraft: Type;Altitude bin;Aircraft: Make/Model;Pilot notified;Damage type;Amount
Airplane;12;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;12;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-240;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;FALSE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;FALSE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-240;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-230;TRUE;Damage;100
Airplane;2;A-240;TRUE;Damage;100
```

code is self explanatory

```
awk -F";" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)h[i]=$i;next} 
                {for(i=1;i<NF;i++)s[$i" - "h[i]]+=$NF} 
             END{for(v in s) print s[v], v}' filename
```

will output

```
1200 Damage - Damage type
200 12 - Altitude bin
1000 TRUE - Pilot notified
200 FALSE - Pilot notified
1000 2 - Altitude bin
900 A-230 - Aircraft: Make/Model
1200 Airplane - Aircraft: Type
300 A-240 - Aircraft: Make/Model
```

pipe to sorting as before for final result.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an array with columns name. you could use split to make your array. Here is a simple example :

```
line="Aircraft: Type;Altitude bin;Aircraft: Make/Model;Pilot notified;Damage type"
split(line,array,";")
print array[1]
```

Comment: How do I associate them with the values from the awk array?

Comment: Depends if it could have same value in differents columns.
if yes - there is no column associated with the value
if no -  you could keep the column name with the value as key of your hash : `{for(i=1;i<=29;i++)sums[$i" - "columns[i]]+=$32}`